# OWASP Guide for web app penetration testing says use "nmap –PN –sT –sV –p0" but in my Kali OS it says failed to resolve

Tags: nmap

On page 35 of the [Owasp testing guide](https://owasp.org/www-project-web-security-testing-guide/assets/archive/OWASP_Testing_Guide_v4.pdf), it says to use Nmap as:

```
nmap –PN –sT –sV –p0-65535 192.168.1.100
```

but running this on my machine with the `-PN -sT -p0` flags gives the following errors:

```
Failed to resolve "–PN".
Failed to resolve "–sT".
Failed to resolve "–sV".
Failed to resolve "–p0-65535".
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: `-PN` is not a valid flag to `nmap`. Read it's help and man page.

Comment: Did you copy+paste the command into your terminal instead of typing it? It looks like the dashes are e2 80 93 EN DASH characters rather than ASCII hyphens - so **none** of your "options" are being recognized as options (hence nmap is attempting to resolve them as hostnames instead)

Answer (score 0):

The errors (`Failed to resolve "–PN"`) give a clue that nmap has not processed your options as options, but as potential targets. [steeldriver](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/65304/steeldriver) noticed that the options are using EN DASH characters rather than ASCII hyphens:

```
–PN –sT –sV –p0-65535
```

instead of:

```
-PN -sT -sV -p0-65535
```

Use this command instead:

```
nmap -PN -sT -sV -p0-65535 192.168.1.100
```

... and you'll get an execution of nmap as you intended.